# Artifacts on external display connected via USB-C hub after sleep (+ few other problems)

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, sleep, usb-c, usb-hub

I wanted to have a setup where I would connect all the devices to a single USB-C hub and then switch between 3 different computers (ASUS Zenbook, Macbook and a stationary PC) just by simply switching which computer is currently connected to the hub.

The hub itself is Unitek uHUB S7+ 7-in-1 (https://www.unitek-products.com/products/uhub-s7-7-in-1-usb-c-hub-with-10gbps-data-hdmi-and-pd-100w). It contains following ports:

- 2x USB 3.2 Gen 2
- 2x USB-C 3.2 Gen 2 - one with Power Delivery, the other one labeled as "10 Gbps"
- 1x HDMI 2.0
- 1x 3.5 mm audio jack (with mic)

A part of the setup is an external display LG 34GP950G-B (https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-34gp950g-b-gaming-monitor) with following ports:

- 1x HDMI 2.1
- 1x DisplayPort 1.4
- 1x USB 3.2 Gen. 1
- 1x USB-B 3.2 Gen. 1

Using the external display and the hub, I connect everything as follows:

- Keyboard and mouse are connected to the display, which is then connected to the hub via USB B <-> USB
- DisplayPort is connected to the PC
- HDMI is connected to the hub
- 65 W charger is connected to the hub's PD port
- hub output is connected to USB-C port of a computer that I'm currently using

My setup, however, doesn't work as expected. Here are the problems I encounter:

1. When I connect my ASUS Zenbook to the hub, the external display starts to have artifacts sometimes. It looks like brief "flashes" of white noise in various parts of the screen. Once in a while the screen goes black for 2 seconds and then the image is back on again. Sometimes, however, it doesn't go back on and the monitor starts displaying "no signal" - here I need to disconnect the hub and connect it again. Now here's the fun part: as soon as I connect Macbook to the very same setup using same devices and cables, there's no sign of such a problem. Why could that be? How to troubleshoot?

   **Update**: I think I was able to narrow it down a bit. It seems to start happening after the computer is put to sleep and then wakes up again. If I then restart my computer, the problem persists, but if I shut down the hub (by disconnecting it from both the charger and the laptop), wait few seconds and connect it again, the problem seems to be gone (or at least in most of cases). My hypothesis are either driver issues or something related to powering the hub. For that matters, the graphic chipset in the affected laptop is Intel Iris Xe.

   **Update 2**: After few trials of the workaround mentioned in the previous update, I no longer think it's a reliable way to fix it. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, I feel like it's pretty random. It was also pointed out in the comments that in the FAQ section of the very specific hub I am using, there's a solution to "Why do I lose the connection of my external monitor when the Windows computer wakes up from sleep mode?" problem which basically is fixed by disabling "USB selective suspend", but turning that off did not fix the problem for me. It is, however, somehow related to sleep, because if it's not happening then it's not happening until the computer sleeps, but once it starts happening there's no reliable fix. I've seen cases where restarting either the computer or the hub did not fix the artifacts.
2. As an idea to overcome that, I bought a 4k UHD 60Hz HDMI 2.0 <-> USB-C 3.1 gen 1 cable with a plan to connect HDMI part to the display and USB-C to the USB-C labeled "10 Gbps" on the hub. However, when I do that, the computer does not see the external display at all. Is there a way to make it work?

   **Update**: It was pointed in the comments that the hub might not support video pass-through.
3. I also have some audio issues. The hub itself has a 3.5 mm audio jack, but honestly I have no idea how it would work - no matter what I connect there, no sound is played. I'm not even sure what would I need to select as sound output device, the hub isn't there. I tried to connect my speakers to the external display, as it has "headphone out" and when I select my external display as sound output it works, but it is extremely quiet - I don't know why. As a temporary solution I used 3.5 mm jack <-> USB C and connect it to the hub, it then is visible as Asus UCB DAC, which works, but ideally I'd like to have this additional USB-C on the hub available.

   **Update**: This is partially solved, the problem with volume was caused by the fact that the monitor, to which I connected the speakers, has its own volume settings, which are not available through settings.
4. When I connect the hub to Zenbook, Windows reports that the charger I use is a slow charger. I do not care that much about that, but shouldn't it have quick charging available? The charger is 65 W (the same value as the stock one I got with the laptop) and hub says it should handle up to 100 W.
5. Might be connected to #1 because it also happens after sleep, but my keyboard, which light color is controlled via Open RGB, also often forgets the selected color after the computer wakes up and when that happens the color cannot be changed unless I order Open RGB to "rescan devices"

How can I solve those problems? I am happy to provide any additional details if needed.

Comment: #3 is partially solved - shame to admit, but I completely forgot that extended display has its own volume settings which are not visible in the settings but only available through joystick that the display uses for navigation and controls. I'm still wondering, though, why connecting audio directly to the hub didn't work, but that's fine. Problem #1 is the most crucial for me now.

Comment: whats the model of your zenbook ?

Comment: On the link you've provided to your hub, have you worked through the tutorial of "Why do I lose the connection of my external monitor when the Windows computer wakes up from sleep mode?" ??

Comment: @1NN The model is Zenbook Flip UX 363E and no, I haven't tried that thing from the FAQ - turned it off just now, will observe it for a day or two. If it turns out to fix my artifacts problems, I'm happy to accept that as the rewarded answer.

Comment: @1NN sounded promising, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference - the problem persists. I even now have a feeling that a workaround I described in the main post also doesn't work.Happy New Year, BTW

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Workaround

Edit your power plan (in cotrol panel-> power optios -> change plan settings) and set Sleep to "never" on plugged in. [Tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2843-change-power-plan-settings-windows-10-a.html)

---

I cannot guarantee the following will work, but its worth a try.

### General steps: driver resets and updates

After each one of these steps, restart your PC and see if it helped. You can also do all of them if you're impatient. Make sure your Hub is DISCONNECTED while you run any of these.

1. Reset the USB root hub by uninstalling it from device manager. Follow the Method 1 from [this tutorial.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/usb-devices-may-stop-functioning-correctly-when-multiple-devices-connected-to-the-same-usb-hub-go-into-selective-suspend-99b5ae85-69cb-4f94-adce-5698ba44804f)
2. Uninstall all USB-device drivers from your system. They will reinstall when you connect them next time. [Follow this tutorial.](https://www.pic-control.com/uninstall-hidden-usb-drivers-from-device-manager/)
3. Update your Intel chipset drivers. [Use this intel webpage](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download-center/home.html) to determine which drivers need update.
4. Check the [Asus website](https://www.asus.com/support) for driver updates for your Zenbook.

### Specific Steps

Some more things you can try:

**Issue 3 (Audio)** :
While your hub is connected, go to Control Panel -> Sound, and in the Playback tab check whether there's some device which is disabled.

**Issue 4 (Fast Charge)** :
Fast charge usually needs a direct negotiation between your PC and the original OEM charger. Such negotiation might not be based on the USB protocol. So if your charger is not directly connected to the PC, this simply won't work.

**Completely disable USB suspend.** For completeness sake, there's  a registry setting to completely disable USB power saving. I myself would not do it. But you can follow Method 3 in [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/usb-devices-may-stop-functioning-correctly-when-multiple-devices-connected-to-the-same-usb-hub-go-into-selective-suspend-99b5ae85-69cb-4f94-adce-5698ba44804f) (same microsoft webpage as above)

### Last resort

If none of this helps, try to contact the OEM of your hub, state your issues and that you've tried the above steps.

Comment: Tried almost everything from the list (except completely disabling USB suspend) - nothing works :( but have a reward for the effort, better than let it waste.
As of #3 (audio), despite having a jack socket, the hub itself does not figure as a playback device in sound settings. This it probably a reason why it doesn't work, but I'm wondering how manufacturer planned it to work in the first place.
The same with #4 then - if you say that it will "simply won't work", I'm wondering why the hub lists "USB Power Delivery up to 100W" as its feature.

Comment: @KubaJagoda #4 You CAN charge with 100W but it depends how your PC's OEM has implemented normal or fast charge: try to use the Asus charger: Fast charge needs a data stream btw the battery and the charger. #3 If the audio works on your Mac, it's a driver issue. Contact the OEM of the Dock and see if they can provide a driver update or firmware update. (If it doesn't work on Mac, the dock might be broken).